# jQuery .click not being recognised

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot figure out what is up with this section of code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testimonialContent').load('http://www.1.co.uk/wp-content/themes/1/testimonialPull.php');
  $('#nextQu').click(function(){
        alert(".");
    return false;
  });
});
```

I am not getting the alerted message when I should be. I dont think I have made any syntaxial errors?

HTML:

```
<?php
    require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
?>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><img id="quoteOne" src="http://www.1.co.uk/wp-content/themes/1/images/quote1.png">
    <span><?php
        query_posts(array(
            'cat' => 39,
            'order' => 'ASC', // ASC
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'showposts' => 1,
            ));
        $wp_query->is_archive = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_content();
        endwhile; endif;


    ?>
    <span id="nextQu">NEXT QUOTE</span>
    </span>
```

Comment: @CodeJack thanks for the response, unfortunately no change

Comment: Is the HTML pasted from the original document (where your document ready is registered), or from the code being loaded into `#testimonialContent`?

Comment: working for me..http://jsfiddle.net/tanveer433/Mw6FG/

Comment: I pasted a shortened version of your code into a fiddle and it works. Have you properly included jQuery in your file? Does Firebug tell you of any JS errors that are thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using delegation:

```
$('#testimonialContent').on('click','#nextQu',function(){
        alert(".");
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks  for the response! This worked a treat. I dont suppose you mind explaining this one to me as I am still trying to learn :) I will mark as correct when it allows, cheers!

Comment: load() is async by default so you were trying to bind event to an non-existent element. Using delegate with .on(), you then bind when element is created/exist. .click() is equivalent to bind() {bind() is now obsolete 1.7+}. .on(event,elem,callback) is equivalent to delegate.